Запуск python файлов и других python файлов в Docker
Моя программа на python запускает два других python файла:
files = ["bot.py", "loop.py"]
    if not get_pid(): #эта функция проверяет запущены ли эти файлы
        for fl in files:
            subprocess.Popen(args=["start", "python", fl], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

запуская это на своем компьютере (windows) все хорошо работает, но стоит мне собрать проект в docker image:
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/bot
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "admin_bot.py"]

и запустить контейнер то в логе появляется ошибка:
python: 1: python: 1: start: not found
о том что файл (наверное, я не уверен) не найден ,эти файлы находятся на самом верхнем уровне в проекте, я не понимаю как они могут быть не найдены, возможно для linux надо как то по другому использовать subprocess.Popen, но я не силен в данной библиотеке, помогите с данной ошибкой

Чего вы пытались добиться использованием команды start? Ну и к питону это конечно никакого отношения не имеет

немного непонятно почему выбран именно такой подход. Если эти файлы статичны и никогда не изменятся, то лучше оформить это функцией и вызвать ее, можно так же в списке. Если же эти файлы могут быть обновлены (через монтирование каталога вне контейнера), то попробуйте указать абсолютный путь к файлам args=["start", "python", f{WORK_DIR}/{fl}],, но учтите, что если вы монтируете каталог к контейнеру, то он заменяет собой тот, что находится внутри, поэтому подготовьте и наполните его предварительно.

Ошибка не про то, что не найдены bot.pyили loop.py, а про то, что Popen не находит команду start. Нет такой команды в линуксе.
